# How get a certain numeric value inside array of string in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, laravel

I have a String `$line`. For example,

```
$line = "stringA stringB 4-stringC stringD stringF 12345 stringG 678249 stringH ";
```

According to the var `$line`, there are 6 words of string, 2 numeric values, and 1  combination word of numeric and string.

I would like to catch a certain string which is a numeric value `12345`. And this is my code that I just tried:

```
if (preg_match('/ ([0-9,]+)/', $line, $matches) === 1 && strlen($matches[0]) > 3 && strlen($matches[1]) > 3) {
    echo var_dump($matches[0]);
}
```

However, It seems like the code only take the first numeric value on the string, once it traced. And the result is:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) " 4"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "4"
}
```

instead of `12345`.

So, What is the 'Regular Expression' should I use, if I only like to catch string contain: `12345` ?

Comment: `\d{5}` to get 5 digits

Comment: post more different strings that you want split plz.

Comment: You can also do this: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/85bb608816c3cbd81520ae7ffe5123bc45c5d5aa

Comment: Well, just to answer your question. You can use `preg_match_all` to get more than one match. Because in your case, only the first match is checked by `preg_match`. Another option would be to rewrite the regex to find the `last occurence`. Or you could reverse the string before using `preg_match` with `strrev` (and then reverse the found match again).

Comment: @jibsteroos how to set get $matches more than 4 digit, and manage in preg_match()? `'/ ([0-9,]+\d{5})/'`

Comment: Use`\b\d{4,}\b`

Comment: @MatthiasS I have tried `preg_match_all` but it didnt show result. Get the `last occurence` could be an solution, however, maybe it could be risky if there are another numeric string after `12345`. Do you have any advice for this?

Comment: @AgnesPalit See https://3v4l.org/49hD7

Comment: @AgnesPalit This post is reopened. Did any of the solutions mentioned in the comments work for you?

Comment: @Thefourthbird yes, your answer is the one that I use and it works well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use word boundaries `\b` and match 4 or more digits using a quantifier `{4,}`

```
\b\d{4,}\b
```

For example

```
$line = "string string 4-string string string 12345 string 678249 string ";
if (preg_match('/\b\d{4,}\b/', $line, $matches)) {
    var_dump($matches);
}
```

Output

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "12345"
}
```

[Php demo](https://3v4l.org/49hD7)